# SimpleCart(js) Multiple Shipping

Tags: javascript

I'm current in the process of setting up a simplecart(js).

I'm struggling with shipping, I want to enable customers to have a choice of shipping.

has anyone been able to do it properly?

---

Thanks for that MadHudev.

I've looked at that a few times but I'm trying to use a DropDown box with a few different shipping options in there.

```
<select class="item_Shipping" id="AddShipping">
<option value="6.00">Royal Mail First Class</option>
<option value="8.00">Next Day Delivery</option>
<option value="9.00">SameDay</option>
</select>
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to make this work. Kindly check this URL - http://healthcurrents.ca/my-shopping-cart.html and view the source for the function findShippingRate() in the head tag

You need to call the functions updateTotals() and updateViewTotals() in order to make it work.

You have a working example at the link I posted above. The only difference is that I use radio buttons instead of a drop-down list in your question.

Regards
Dinesh

Answer (score 0):

You can check this documentation

- http://simplecartjs.com/documentation.html

Under a configuration->shipping, you can see a shipping adding information.